# Remove tax if over x value in magento

Tags: magento

Hello :)
Can anyone help me how to remove shipping value, if the total order is over 100 euro for example.

So if the order i under 100 euro, there need to be a extra shipping tax, but if the order is over 100 euro, there don't need to be a shipping tax.

Hope someone can help :-)

Comment: when you say "shipping tax", do you mean "shipping fee"?  Tax has a particular meaning such as GST, VAT or other government charge.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly your wanting to change tax rates based off the order total?  NY, USA has something similar to this called Luxury Tax I had to find a means to do such.  Here's what I found, as it may not be a direct solution to your problem but can at least give you a starting point code wise.  Obviously exhaust all core abilities of Magento first to make sure its NOT possible before attempting such, as there may be a means without code changes, more details on your question would help, anyhow...

```
protected function _unitBaseCalculation($item, $request)
    {
        // If USD and from NY Region, apply tax rate based on grand total
        if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode() == "USD" && $request['region_id'] == "43") {
            if($item['discount_amount'] != 0) {
                $package_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item['product_id'])->getAttributeText('package_id');
                if($package_id == "SHOES") {
                    $price_minus_discount = $item['price'] - $item['discount_amount'];
                    if($price_minus_discount < 110) {
                        //$rate = "4.375";
                        $item->getProduct()->setTaxClassId('7');
                    } else {
                        //$rate = "8.875";
                        $item->getProduct()->setTaxClassId('6');
                    }
                }
            }
```

http://www.molotovbliss.com/ny-luxury-taxes-with-discounts-and-magento